Is it possible to travel to Uppsala from Stockholm with SL unlimited card?
Is it possible to travel to Uppsala from Stockholm with SL unlimited card? I know the Commuter rail needs additional fare ticket but was thinking if it is possible to travel to Marsta and take any bus 982 that is covered under SL ticket to Uppsala.

You'll always require a UL ticket, which costs 39 kr for adults, or 27 kr for students, seniors and youths aged below 20. Bus 982 is only covered by the SL ticket within the Stockholm fare zone.
Fast trains between central Stockholm and Uppsala will cost you at least 95 kr and are sold at www.sj.se.
